# Download file from google drive to local folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, google-drive-api

Good morning everyone
I'm trying to download a file from google drive to a local folder (eg download folder).

This is the action of the controller

```
public IActionResult ViewDocument(string id)
    {
        DownloadedFile file = GdS.DownloadFile(id);

        return File(file.Contents, file.FileType);
    }
```

DownloadedFile is a class

```
public class DownloadedFile
        {
            public MemoryStream Contents{ get; set; }
            public string FileType{ get; set; }
        }
```

which I'm going to instantiate whith this function in class GdS

```
public DownloadedFile DownloadFile(string id)
        {
            var getRquest = GetDriveService().Files.Get(id);
            getRquest.SupportsTeamDrives = true;
            var file = getRquest.Execute();
            MemoryStream ms = new();
            getRquest.Download(ms);

            new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider().TryGetContentType(file.Name, out string contentType);

            return new() { Contents = ms, FileType = contentType };
        }
```

GetDriveService() is a Function tha get the GoogleDriveService of Google API.

I still receive error http 500.

The GoogleDriveService gives no errors

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you debug you code? Which line in the code throws the exception?

Comment: When I debug I don't throw an exception but I only receive a blank page with HTTP error 500

Comment: Are you debug thru all the line of code inside `DownloadFile` method? Do you see blank page after execution of `return new() { Contents = ms, FileType = contentType };` ?

Comment: Yes to both questions
But now I fixed it.
Now I write how I solved it

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed in this way

```
public IActionResult ViewDocument(string id)
        {
            DownloadedFile file = GdS.DownloadFile(id);

            return File(file.Contents, file.FileType, file.FileName);
        }
```

I've added a property to DownLoadedFile class

```
public class DownloadedFile
        {
            public byte[] Contents { get; set; }
            public string FileType { get; set; }
            public string Filename { get; set; }
        }
```

which I instantiate with this

```
public DownloadedFile DownloadFile(string id)
        {
            var getRquest = GetDriveService().Files.Get(id);
            getRquest.SupportsTeamDrives = true;
            var file = getRquest.Execute();
            using MemoryStream ms = new();
            getRquest.Download(ms);

            new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider().TryGetContentType(file.Name, out string contentType);

            return new() { Contents = ms.ToArray(), Filename = file.Name, FileType = contentType };
        }
```

now it works

Thanks to everyone